# Json files are not displaying data

Tags: javascript, json

I have this problem where I try to read a Json file (that is in the same directory as my html page) but whenever I run the application is shows [this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ES1Th.png)[(This is my html page - code behind)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vjVrg.png)


**.jSON file -**

```
[
    { "_id":"1", "description":"Samsung Note 4", "price":899, "image": "samsung-note4.png", "platform":"Android Jellybean" }, 
    { "_id":"2", "description":"iPhone 6", "price":1028, "image": "iphone6.png", "platform":"iOS 8" }, 
    {"_id": "3","description": "HTC One (M8)","price": 768,"image": "htc-one.png","platform": "Windows 8"}
]
```

**This is my JS file -**

```
App.controller('ProductController', function($scope, $http){

   $http.get('products.json')
   .then(function(res){
      $scope.products = res.data;                
    });

    $scope.selectProduct = function (id) {
        $scope.product = _.where($scope.products, {_id: id})[0];
    }
});
```

I do not know why I cannot get the data in the jSON file. any possible reasons why?

Comment: Can you check the network tab in console and tell me what is response of AJAX request ? It can help to detect issue. Use chrome dev tools

Comment: What do you get when you console.log(res) after your $http.get method runs?

Answer (score 0):

This part needs correction:

```
.then(function(res){
      $scope.products = res;                
    });
```

Since res is that parsed JSON data. No need to use `res.data`

Comment: AngularJS returns the content of the JSON file in a data property, https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

Comment: Can someone also confirm that. I don't think that is true unless configured in `$httpProvider.defaults.transformRequest`

Answer (score 0):

try lowercase p in 'product' in your ng-repeat

```
<li ng-repeat="product in products" >
 {{ product.image }}
```

in your controller, try this:

```
.when(function(data){
  $scope.products = data;
});
```

The response object has these properties:

- data – {string|Object} – The response body transformed with the
  transform functions.
- status – {number} – HTTP status code of the response.
- headers – {function([headerName])} – Header getter function.
- config – {Object} – The configuration object that was used to
  generate the request.
- statusText – {string} – HTTP status text of the response.

Comment: Yep, this seems like the possible suspect!

Comment: I changed it but it still cannot work... hmm I suspect it is the controller.js issue

Comment: if you console.log(data) in the .when function, do you see the json object in your browser console?